# how to calculate percentage % of 2 values with $ sign on web page

Tags: javascript, themes, bigcommerce

I want to get percentage of 2 values with $ signs, like this:

```
$2,299.00, $2,199.00...
```

but from back-end, I can use website tags as below:

```
<span>{{price.rrp_with_tax.formatted}}</span>
<span>{{price.with_tax.formatted}}</span>
```

these prices only appear on website, how can I calculate these values on page for all items having 2 prices as a loop ? I want to show 4% OFF

Comment: please show you code in code snippet, how you receive the values from backend and represent in HTML.

Comment: You could use a regular expression to remove the `$` and `,` effectively resulting in an javascript Number which you can perform standard calculations on. As Shiv states, you should post the code for a more solid answer.

Comment: First of all share what you tried then we can do something.

Comment: please share your current code

Answer (score 0):

Add a span below those spans like below, you can do it simply with handlebars.

```
<span>Save {{../../settings.money.currency_token}} {{divide (multiply (price.rrp_with_tax.formatted) 100) price.with_tax.formatted}}%</span>
```